# Android SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, database

I have values in server json url and getting those values then storing into local database. But when i get those values and storing into local database i'm getting Failed to open database.

```
SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.testjson/databases/Details", null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                checkDB.close();


                db.updateDetails(store);


            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                // database doesn't exist yet.

                // Log.i("DatabaseInserted", "No Found");

                 db.insertDetails(store);

            }
```

Log:

```
12-15 17:23:17.555: E/SQLiteLog(17270): (14) cannot open file at line 32516 of [00bb9c9ce4]
12-15 17:23:17.555: E/SQLiteLog(17270): (14) os_unix.c:32516: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.beacon/databases/BeaconDetails) - 
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.beacon/databases/BeaconDetails'.
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:339)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:236)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:891)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:859)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at com.example.beacon.MainActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:226)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at com.example.beacon.MainActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-15 17:23:17.560: E/SQLiteDatabase(17270):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are closing the Db before making update or insert!

swap the statements to:

```
db.updateDetails(store);
checkDB.close();
```

Comment: if my database is not existing, i should insert the details db.insertDetails(store);

Comment: not exactly!! if db not existing first you have to create it and then you can insert/update!!

Comment: Yes you are closing database before inserting or updating data